# Show page numbers as navigation in Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I ma using Laravel 9 and it renders previous,next button for pagination. How could I change it to page numbers.

It shows :
< Previous , Next >

What I want is:
< 1 2 3 4 >

In controller I got:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::orderBY('id','desc')->paginate(2)->withQueryString();
    return view('panel.users.index', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

In blade template I got:

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Laravel 9 used Tailwind CSS. To use these views instead of the default Tailwind views, you may call the paginator's `useBootstrap` method within the `boot` method of your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    Paginator::useBootstrapFour();
}
```

official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make some changes in tailwind.config.js file and include the vendor file like:

```js
content: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
],
```